# Can extjs Control/toggle groupField data?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

### here is the example edited by crop grid:

1st i view like a normal grid like this image

http://imageshack.us/f/836/groupcontrollingb4.png/

then i create a check box name as "Cuisine:American" and check it to reload become image like this

http://imageshack.us/f/803/gridcontrollingafter.png/

the group data "Cuisine:American" can be group it and expand 
then other data still remain the normal grid view

Does any one know a example or possibility for controlling the groupView like in the example i've shown ?

Hope u all can understand my question
thankz.

Comment: You can always group by `Cusine==American` expression, so you'll have 2 groups: American and Others

Comment: This is just a sort of 'write me some code' for me. Provide some code what you have tried so far and not just images...

Comment: @.@ here the codes if u need,
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/groupgrid.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's harder than it should be, because ext is not calling `Ext.util.Grouper.getGroupString` method. I've managed to bypass this. Here is working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/bP7Y2/

I am basing on [Grouped Grid Example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/groupgrid.html) from Ext JS site. I've created `CuisineGrouper` which is extending `Ext.util.Grouper`. There are 2 important methods: `getGroupString` which returns gruping string and `sorterFn` which sorts in that way that grupped elements are on the top. For example when there is grouping by 'Cuisine:American'  `getGroupString` returns 'American' or '' depending on `cuisine` value.

Another important bit is overriden `getGroupString` method on `Restaurants` store, so now it calls `Ext.util.Grouper.getGroupString`.

Last thing I've modified is `groupHeaderTpl` of `groupingFeature`.

(Update) It's possible to hide Others grouping header with some hacks. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bP7Y2/1/

Comment: Is that Possible i content 3 group of Cuisine(American,Indian,Others) in that grid? 
And this method only can use in extjs 4?or both?

Comment: @user983738 You can group by whatever you want, even 7 groups. You have ready code, it's not a big deal to modify it. It's definetely harder to acomplish that in ExtJS 3, because there is no such class like Grouper. It's not impossible though. My idea of doing that is to create additional field in each record (probably hidden column in grid would also be required) and put there group value before invoking grouping method.

Comment: how to define 2 value in here?
 Restaurants.group(new CuisineGrouper({ value: 'Indian' }), 'DESC');

Comment: You must modify CuisineGrouper in that way it would be possible to pass more than 1 value to it. Eg. http://jsfiddle.net/bP7Y2/9/